# Check that TopicClient will work without error

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm writing C# code which will send a message to the Azure ServiceBus thus (simplified for clarity):

```
private ITopicClient topicClient
 = new TopicClient(configuration["ServiceBusEndpoint"], configuration["ServiceBusTopic"]);

// test here

await topicClient.SendAsync(messageToSend.ToString());
```

What I'd like to do, if possible, is conduct some sort of test/check that the `SendAsync()` method is *likely* to have a good chance of succeeding before I call it, rather than have to catch any and all exceptions when it doesn't.

That is to say, that there is a valid, open connection to the ServiceBus, and it is ready to accept the message.

I can't find any info on how to do this from the various documents I've read online...

Has anyone else faced this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's a property `IsClosedOrClosing` you could read to verify connection is still there, it is not going to remove the need to handle exceptions.

Connection could die in the middle. Or you could get throttled. Or there could be a network glitch that would result in timeout. Or it could be a transient error where your code is expected to retry. There are [plenty of exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) that can take place and you need to handle those.

In general, you want to look at the exceptions and determine if a retry is going to help (error is transient) or not. While the client has a retry policy built in, sometimes that's not enough. Especially when working with the Standard Tier where you could get throttled.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I wasn't planning to have no exception handling; I just wanted to be reasonably certain the call was going to succeed. This is because I have to do some other work, then send a message about it... I don't want want to do that work if there's no hope of the message send working (as that work can't be undone if the message send fails)....

Comment: You could do the rest of the work as a continuation of the sending task, assuming you use async call. That way, you have total control what happens if the call is successful or not. At the same time, when you `await` for sending operation, you're promissed that the message will be either sent or will fail with an exception, so no further work will take place. Unless, you're doing "fire and forget", which I'd recommend against in this case.

Comment: Sean, what I probably didn't make 100% clear is the 'other work' and the sending of the message should, taken together, really be an atomic transaction. The trouble is, neither the 'other work' nor the message sending can be 'rolled back' or undone should the other task fail....

Comment: Perhaps instead of trying to roll-back, you might to evaluate idempotency and chain of actions. [Outbox](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/) is another pattern that can help.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Certainly both the 'other work' and message sending can be considered idempotent - performing either multiple times is not a problem. Outbox looks useful, but in this particular case, the 'other work' isn't a database update, and isn't/can't be made transnational, so that pattern cant be applied As a possible work-around, I test for IsClosedOrClosing, as advised, and attempt to send the message multiple times until it succeeds or the loop expires and an error is logged. Time will tell if this approach proves reliable or not...